# Durandal - Multiple routes using same VM/View

Tags: mvvm, durandal

I'm building an application using Durandal 2. I want to define multiple routes using the same VM/View for different context.

Exemple :

1. /sectionA/:id/home using module ID /viewmodels/home
2. /sectionB/:id/home using module ID /viewmodels/home too

At first, sectionA and sectionB are meant to use the exact same VM and Views. But, eventually, they will be different. This is not where the issue is since when they'll be different, they'll have their very own VM and shared views (using MVC partials) which will work straight out the box.

The point is, for as long as the page are the same, we don't want to duplicate the VM and Views, generating a lot of garbage for nothing.

I tried the example shown above but that doesn't seems to be possible to do this. Whether the routes are different, it seems that the router cannot make the difference between the two routes and just throw a "route not found" exception although the route is defined in our route definition file.

So the question, is it possible to define two route, with obviously different routes definitions, but using the same moduleId?

If more details are require, don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you post the router config you have made?

Comment: Also please just try out to call the route without the :id param. I suspect the parameter is what makes it break. Sry couldn't edit the comment anymore

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I found out that its working right out the box the way I illustrated it above. I'll answer my own post when I'll have some time free :)